PostgreSQL - Json data - Inserting into Target Table through Trigger
This is continuation to similar post.
I have a students_source table with a json column like this.
CREATE TABLE students_source (doc_id INT, doc_data JSON);
A row is inserted with doc_id = 201. The insert statement is:
INSERT INTO xereports.students_data(doc_id, doc_data) 
VALUES (201, '{
  "document_type": "students_report",
  "document_name": "students_report_202406.pdf",
  "data": {
    "grades": [
      {
        "grade_name": "5",
        "sections": {
          "5A_students": [
            {
              "student_name": "Arun",
              "avg_marks": 85,
              "rank": "AA+"
            },
            {
              "student_name": "Bala",
              "avg_marks": 70,
              "rank": "A+"
            }
          ],
          "5B_students": [
            {
              "student_name": "Chitra",
              "avg_marks": 86,
              "rank": "AA+"
            },
            {
              "student_name": "David",
              "avg_marks": 72,
              "rank": "A+"
            }
          ],
          "5C_students": [
            {
              "student_name": "Elango",
              "avg_marks": 88,
              "rank": "AA+"
            },
            {
              "student_name": "Fathima",
              "avg_marks": 74,
              "rank": "A+"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "grade_name": "6",
        "sections": {
          "6A_students": [
            {
              "student_name": "Arun2",
              "avg_marks": 85,
              "rank": "AA+"
            },
            {
              "student_name": "Bala2",
              "avg_marks": 70,
              "rank": "A+"
            }
          ],
          "6B_students": [
            {
              "student_name": "Chitra2",
              "avg_marks": 86,
              "rank": "AA+"
            },
            {
              "student_name": "David2",
              "avg_marks": 72,
              "rank": "A+"
            }
          ],
          "6C_students": [
            {
              "student_name": "Elango2",
              "avg_marks": 88,
              "rank": "AA+"
            },
            {
              "student_name": "Fathima2",
              "avg_marks": 74,
              "rank": "A+"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}');

The requirement is that whenever such record is inserted, a subset of the data should be inserted into a target table. i.e., all the AA+ student details to be captured. Like this...

The structure of the target table is:
CREATE TABLE students_target (
  doc_id INT,
  document_type VARCHAR(500),
  document_name VARCHAR(500),
  grade_name VARCHAR(500),
  student_name VARCHAR(500),
  avg_marks int,
  rank_cd varchar(100) 
);

I am able to query the data from the source table.
select
    sd.doc_id,
    sd.doc_data ->> 'document_type' as document_type,
    sd.doc_data ->> 'document_name' as document_name,
    grade ->> 'grade_name' as grade_name,
    student->>'student_name' as student_name,
    student->>'avg_marks' as avg_marks,
    student->>'rank' as rank
from
    students_source sd,
    json_array_elements(doc_data->'data'->'grades') as grade,
    json_each(grade->'sections') as section(key, value),
    json_array_elements(section.value) as student
where
    student->>'rank' = 'AA+'
    and sd.doc_id = 201;

But while creating Trigger Function, I get error.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION student_data_triger_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO students_target 
    (doc_id, document_type, document_name, grade_name, student_name, avg_marks, rank_cd)
VALUES(
    NEW.doc_id,
    NEW.doc_data ->> 'document_type',
    NEW.doc_data ->> 'document_name',
    grade ->> 'grade_name',
    student->>'student_name',
    student->>'avg_marks',
    student->>'rank'
from
    NEW sd,
    json_array_elements(NEW.doc_data->'data'->'grades') as grade,
    json_each(grade->'sections') as section(key, value),
    json_array_elements(section.value) as student
where
    student->>'rank' = 'AA+'
    )
       RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

I get this error.

How to fix this?

Expressions in a VALUES clause cannot have an output name.

Hi @JohnH, corrected the VALUES. But not the error at FROM clause. How to query from NEW? (The recent error message shown in the question.)

Did you mean SELECT instead of VALUES?

Hi @Bergi, not sure on how to fetch data from NEW. I tried with SELECT. Please suggest if any better way to fetch data from NEW record.

The correct syntax is INSERT … SELECT …;, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html
No VALUES, no parenthesis.
INSERT INTO xereports.students_data_extract 
    (doc_id, document_type, document_name, grade_name, student_name, avg_marks, rank_cd)
SELECT
    NEW.doc_id,
    NEW.doc_data ->> 'document_type',
    NEW.doc_data ->> 'document_name',
    grade ->> 'grade_name',
    student->>'student_name',
    student->>'avg_marks',
    student->>'rank'
FROM
    json_array_elements(NEW.doc_data->'data'->'grades') as grade,
    json_each(grade->'sections') as section(key, value),
    json_array_elements(section.value) as student
WHERE
    student->>'rank' = 'AA+';


Hi @Bergi, it works now.
Also int cast as (student->>'avg_marks')::int, corrected the function.
